# passportjs jwt, client response not getting authenticated

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

trying to implement login with passport-JWT. both signup and login work fine, token is produced on login and sent to client that stores and returns it back.

After login authentication request reaches app and nothing happens.. Help? :)

JWT Strategy

```
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
    ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
    var opts = {}
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
    opts.secretOrKey = 'secret';
    opts.issuer = "http://localhost:3000";
    opts.audience = "http://localhost:3000";

    passport.use('jwt', new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) { 
        console.log(1)
        return User
            .findOne({where : {username : jwt_payload.email } })
            .then(function (user) {
                if(user === null){
                    return TempUser
                            .findOne({where : {username : jwt_payload.email } })
                            .then(function(user){
                                return user === null ? 
                                    done(null, false, 'login error, please try again') :
                                    done(null, false, 'email verification needed');
                            });
                } else {
                    if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.dataValues.password)){        
                            done(null, user); 
                    } else {
                        done(null, false, 'login error, please try again');
                    }

            }
        });
    }));
```

Route

```
router.get('/login/check', function(req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('jwt', function(err, user, info) {
            console.log(err)
            res.json({'success' : true});
        })
    })
```

req.query returned by client

```
GET /login/check?%22eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJzaGFpLmthcGx1bkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJwYXN
zd29yZCI6IiQyYSQxMCQ0YXpvSlVLMkltUkl3YWo0Uzlqd1RPVXh0RWIwYWphNW92UjRvUnV1QUFRdnJ5Z3g5cWttNiIsImNyZWF0ZWRBdCI6IjIwMTYtMDg
tMDdUMTM6MjI6NDYuMzUyWiIsInVwZGF0ZWRBdCI6IjIwMTYtMDgtMDdUMTM6MjI6NTkuOTExWiIsImlhdCI6MTQ3MDY1NzY0MCwiZXhwIjoxNDcwNzU3NjQ
wfQ.hyHDcmzJne-d6roRXBgC9aQDeZzQPgpkWWOZicQNc8c%22 - - ms - -
```

Answer (score 1):

You are telling Passport-JWT to look in the authorization header for the JWT, but it seems you are trying to pass the JWT as a query string.

Try sending a header:
Authentication: "JWT " + token

I actually wrote a tutorial for both the front and back ends of this, which you might find helpful.

http://blog.slatepeak.com/refactoring-a-basic-authenticated-api-with-node-express-and-mongo/

http://blog.slatepeak.com/build-a-react-redux-app-with-json-web-token-jwt-authentication/

Comment: yeah, figured the same. But setting token in header from client side didn't help my case.. what i did was stop using passport-jwt and am now just relying on the jsonwebtoken library for sign/verify